# Undefined Javascript variable using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Javacript API to draw a polyline. I intended to create a function to remove the polyline when a button is clicked. The HTML code for the button is the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear_button" onclick="removeLine()">Borrar ruta</button>
```

and the Javascript code for the drawing the polyline and removing it is the next:

```
    var map;
    var flightPath;
    function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: {lat: 37.176709, lng: -3.599057},
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('route_button'), 'click', function() {
            var date_data = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
            console.log(date_data);
            $.ajax({
                url:"data_fetcher.php",
                type:"POST",
                data: {date_value:date_data},        
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(respond){
                    var flightPlanCoordinates = respond; 
                    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 2
                    });
                     flightPath.setMap(map);        
                     console.log("AJAX level request was successful");
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log("AJAX level request was a failure");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // Eliminar polilinea
    function removeLine() {
    flightPath.setMap(null);
  }
```

everything works fine, but when I click the button to remove the polyline, the console throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined
>       at removeLine (device.php:101)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (device.php:196)

even though I declared flightPath var in the global scope. Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the success function, you're **declaring** a local variable with the same name, JS will use the *closest* variable it finds when **assigning** variables. To fix this simply remove the `var`.

```
success: function (respond) {
    var flightPlanCoordinates = respond;
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    console.log("AJAX level request was successful");
},
```

Comment: Thanks so much George. That was the issue. Can't figure how I couldn't see it.